# How would you force a status code from an nginx proxy at all times, including nginx timeout?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

We have an NGINX proxy and we need the proxy to override the origin response and ALWAYS send 204. We also need to have timeouts setup and still respond 204 status code.

What am I doing wrong?

```
          error_page 404 /__no_content;
          error_page 403 /__no_content;
          error_page 500 /__no_content;
          error_page 200 /__no_content;
          error_page 504 /__no_content;

          location = /__no_content {
                   allow all;
                  return 204 '';
         }

          location / {
                  limit_req zone=req_zone burst=10 nodelay;
                  proxy_read_timeout 80;
                  proxy_connect_timeout 80;
                  proxy_send_timeout 80;
                  proxy_intercept_errors on;

                  # include /etc/nginx/includes/proxy.conf;
                  proxy_pass http://api:10000;
          }
```

Comment: You don't say what happens and what doesn't work. But looking at the [`error_page` manual page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page), the correct way to change the response code is: `error_page 404 =204 /__no_content;` - also, I haven't tested this, but I wouldn't think 200 would be intercepted as an error.